# Object not found in heapdump comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, heap-dump

I've installed `heapdump` nodejs module in order to dump the heap object.

Using this code (nodejs6.9.1),

```
'use strict'
const heapdump = require('heapdump')
heapdump.writeSnapshot()
const obj = {
  test: 2,
  foo: 6.4,
  wow: true,
  a: { }
}
heapdump.writeSnapshot()
console.log(obj) // <-- make sure obj lives until here
```

I've printed two heap dumps.

Importing both of them into chrome dev tools and switching to the comparison mode, I'm aspecting to see the `obj` object at least (with some other values).

Instead, I see only those values:

```
(compiled code)
(array)
(system)
(concatenated
(string)
```

Why?

EDIT:
moving the code into a setTimeout, the dump diff shows the two Objects correctly

```
setTimeout(() => {
  heapdump.writeSnapshot()
  const obj = {
    test: 2,
    foo: 6.4,
    wow: true,
    a: { }
  }
  heapdump.writeSnapshot()
  console.log(obj)
}, 1000)
```

NB: test and foo property is not in dump diff.

Comment: you should use a valid **callback** as the docs suggested: [node headump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump).. the author is actually aware of that **"hitch"** effect

Answer (score 0):

This code illustrates my comment for this question

```
heapdump.writeSnapshot()
 const obj = {
 test: 2,
 foo: 6.4,
 wow: true,
 a: { }
}
heapdump.writeSnapshot(function(err, filename) { // this is the callback
 console.log(obj);
})
```